# Is it better to range over channel or use select?

Tags: go

guys i was wondering if it is better to to range over channel or use select, if I have only one case (my channel) and signal the end with close of the given channel ?

Given the examples:

#### 1. https://play.golang.org/p/3ZFdbgHSKyN

```
go func() {
    for v := range ch {
        // do some stuff
    }
}()
```

#### 2. https://play.golang.org/p/iCCkDge8j72

```
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case v, ok := <-ch:
            if !ok {
                return
            }

            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}()
```

Which solution would be preferred and why ? Please consider the fact that goroutines as such might be spawned many times (many workers).

Comment: @CeriseLimón ye i said it is a select with one case

Comment: Select with one case is like a switch with just a default case: Use such stuff excessively in obfuscation contests.

Comment: @CeriseLimón feel free to move your comment to an answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unless there's another branch of the select, use the following:

```
for v := range ch {
    // do some stuff
}
```

The code is simpler and easier to understand than the for/select presented in the question.

If you need to do the receive inside the loop for some reason, then use the following code:

```
 for  { 
     // do some stuff
     v, ok := <-ch
     if !ok { 
        break 
     } 
     // do some other stuff
 }
```

As a rule of thumb, single branch select statements should be avoided. A select with a single branch is functionally the same as the branch alone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply awaiting on a done channel where you do not need the value returned, then you can drop the for loop entirely as the chan will block. Eg

```
// Verbose
go func() {
    for {
        select {
            case <-blah.Context.Done():
                // Cleanup/Close
                return
        }
    }
}()

// Simplified
go func() {
    <-blah.Context.Done():
    // Cleanup/Close (No return required either)
}()
```

Comment: That's exactly what my "simplified" version does, there is no for loop? Did you only see the verbose/incorrect version? Even in my comment "then you can drop the for loop entirely"